# Subdomain link in view with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, subdomain

I'm currently using subdomains in my Rails 4.2 app.

I can create url with subdomains like this one in my controllers:

```
redirect_to subdomain: 'cloud', controller: '/home', action: 'login'
```

However, I can't create links with subdomains in my views:

```
<%= link_to t(:LOG_OUT), { :subdomain => 'services', :controller => 'users', :action => 'logout' } %>
```

=> the subdomain doesn't change for the one wanted (services). I try also url_for(), same thing. What's wrong ?

Comment: One way would be to just specify the actual url. Something like `services.example.com/users/logout`.

Comment: But I don't want to build myself the url, I want the Rails helpers to do that (including current locale for example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use subdomains in some of our apps,and have found that you have to use the `_url` helper (as opposed to the [`_path` helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers)):

[image]

```
#config/routes
constraints subdomain: "admin" do
  namespace :admin, path: "" do
    ...
  end
end
```

We call it using the following:

[image]

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.admin? && resource.admin_redirect?
    admin_root_url
```

--

So you'll be able to do the following:

```
<%= link_to "Logout", services_users_logout_url %>
```

This will use the full URL for the link (which could be problematic), but should work okay. The path won't work because it's *relative*. You have to use the *url* because then it sets the subdomain.

Comment: Rich, I didn't know that kind of url could work with a routes without ressources ! Great, just learning something nice.

Comment: Great answer. But I should advise you to use StackOverflow's [syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Sorry, yes I had a habit of copy/pasting code. I'll change now